# Getting wrong address from ipaddress.IPv4Network in Python

Tags: python, ip-address, ipv4

I'm using ipaddress library to obtain IP address with subnet mask, but it returns wrong address after putting all data.
What's the problem? When I used it earlier it was working fine.

```
import ipaddress
myip=ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.13.192.123/3',strict=False)
```

The output is 192.0.0.0/3 instead of 192.13.192.123/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **IPv4Network** and not **ip_address**.

`myip = ipaddress.ip_address('192.13.192.123')` will return 192.13.192.123

`myip = ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.13.192.123/24', strict=False)` will return 
**192.13.192.0/24** because the **netmask** is **255.255.255.0**

`myip = ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.13.192.123/3', strict=False)` will return 
**192.0.0.0/24** because the **netmask** is **224.0.0.0**

Comment: is there a method that will return 'ip/subnet mask' ?

Comment: Use **ipaddress.IPv4Interface**